# Mongoose sum fields with the same values

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have mongoose schema like so:

```
const RecordSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    day: Number,
    week: Number,
    month: String,
    year: Number,
    state: String,
    station: String,
    revenue: Number,
    sales: Number,
    date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now()
    }
})
```

I'm trying to write a query where I can get all the states, then sum up the revenue of all the states that have the same name. Something like this:

```
{...state: LH, revenue: 1200}
{...state: PH, revenue: 300}
{...state: LH, revenue: 300}
{...state: PH, revenue: 250}
```

I want to get all these records in one query like so:

```
[{state: PH, revenue: 550}, {state: LH, revenue: 1450}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to use plain `$group` with accumulator

```
 db.collection.aggregate({ //Single pipeline, hence no array notation
   $group:{
     _id: "$state", //Index on state field will improve performance
     revenue: {$sum: $revenue} //accumulator
   }
 })
```

Comment: I'm getting a response that $state is undefined. Do I need to write out the state in it's entirety?

Comment: Use quotes please.

Comment: Okay, it works now. Is there a way I can chain on a find() method so I can filter out the particular year and other things?

Previously, my query was something like Record.find({year: req.params.year, month: req.params.month}). 

Right now, it's basically finding the sum of all the revenues for the entire year

Comment: You need to use `$match` as the first stage. Put the same contents as in find. Then second stage has to be $group.

Comment: This is my updated code:

```
router.get('/revenue/week/:year/:week', (req, res) => {
    Record.aggregate([
        {
            $match: {
                'week': req.params.week
            }
        }, {
            $group: {
                _id: "$state",
                revenue: {
                    $sum: "$revenue"
                }
            }
        }
    ]).exec((err, record) => {
        err && res.send('Something went wrong')
        res.send(JSON.stringify(record))
    })
})
```
But it's returning empty.